# Dynamic content with AngularJS and prettyprint

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pretty-print

There are some code blocks `<pre>...</pre>` with dynamic content by angularJS, which have to be pretty printed. When content updated, in `html` `view` there are both of them - old one and new (on next update - three, and so on..)

**html**

```html
<div ng-repeat="(index, issue) in issues track by $index">
  . . .
  <div>
    <pre class="prettyprint linenums">{{issue.code}}</pre>
  </div>
  . . .
</div>
```

that is not correct.. each issue should have only it's own code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by wrapping content into `<div>` and using `$sce`:

**html**

```html
<div ng-repeat="(index, issue) in issues track by $index">
  . . .
  <div ng-bind-html="getCode(issue.code)"></div>
  . . .
</div>
```

**controller**

```js
app.controller('appCtrl', ['$scope', '$sce', function(scope, sce) {
  ...
  scope.getCode = function(code) {
    // console.log(code);
    return sce.trustAsHtml("<pre class='prettyprint linenums'>" + code + "</pre>");
  };
  ...
}
```

after each content update pretty print method should be called

```js
PR.prettyPrint(); // google-code-prettify
```